# Toolbar doesn't show the overflow icon

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I'm using the new `Toolbar` instead of the `ActionBar`.
On Android 5.0 everything is just fine:

[image]
On 4.4 it doesn't show the Overflow icon (though the function is there):

[image]

This is the `toolbar.xml` I'm using:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/HeaderBar"
    app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText"
    app:contentInsetStart="?actionBarInsetStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `styles.xml` it is needed to add the color for pre 5.0 versions:

```
<style name="Theme.APP.Base" parent="Theme">
    <item name="actionBarIconColor">#fff</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and this code this error ->No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'actionBarIconColor'.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use `ActionBarAcitivity`  if you don't already,
and then set

```
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

or inherit from another theme from `AppCompat`

also in your onCreate you should set the tool bar as your actionbar:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

source: [chris bane's blog](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)